# Existence of supremum in matrix norm definition

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, matrix-norms

My Numerical Analysis professor defined matrix p-norm in today's class as

$$ ||A||_p = \sup_{||y||_p=1} ||Ay||_p $$

My question is how can we guarantee that the supremum exists in the first place?

Comment: Why would it not exist? Intuitively: $A$ is fixed $\rightarrow$ its elements are bounded, $y$ is bounded, $\Rightarrow$ the elements of $Ay$ are also bounded. Does this make sense?

Comment: Oh yes! Thanks @GFrazao